# Using Assertions outside of Tests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assertions

I'd like to start putting assertions in my controllers and models, to assert runtime behavior.

How can I access all of the assertion helpers that are available in unit tests?

I.E. I'd like to do something like

```
class WidgetController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @widgets = Widget.all
        assert @widgets.length > 0 # using assert in a controller!
     end
end
```

Is there just a file I should require?

Comment: to what end? in that context, asserting doesn't _mean_ anything, because you're not in a test.

Comment: Assertiona are made to automatic tests, and shouldn't be putted in controllers or modeles.

Comment: Why not catch (or at least assert) unexpected behavior in production as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple - just require test/unit/assertions:

```
require 'test/unit/assertions'
include Test::Unit::Assertions
```